# Проверка, есть ли определенная переменная в .json файле

Tags: discord, discord.py

пытаюсь сделать что-то похожее на регистрацию в чат-игре на Python для Discord. Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог зарегистрировать в ней только один раз. Сама регистрация работает отлично, но проверка абсолютно нет. Можете ли вы как-то помочь, пожалуйста?

```
@bot.command()
async def getstart(ctx):
    await ctx.send('placeholder (welcome message here)')
    with open("config.json") as feedsjson:
        feeds = json.load(feedsjson)
        if not {"name": f"{ctx.message.author.id}"} in feeds:
            await ctx.send('placeholder (we can add user in json file)..')
            getstartinsocialcredit(ctx.message.author.id, 0)
        else:    
            return await ctx.send('placeholder (user already in json file)')
```

Что должно получиться по итогу. Пользователь регистрируется один раз, а далее, если он вновь напишет команду *(скажем sc.getstart)*, то ему напишет бот: **"Вы уже в Базе! Не могу вас добавить вновь"**, или по что-то похожее.

Comment: А также вот что находится в .json-файле:



```[
  {
    "name": 995336851030290462,
    "sc": 0
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вашего решения в том, что вы сравниваете словарь `{"name": f"{ctx.message.author.id}"}` с `{"name": 995336851030290462, "sc": 0}`, что никогда равно не будет, т.к во втором случае в словаре есть ключ "sc".

Могу предложить вот такое решение взамен:

```
l = [{"name": 995336851030290462, "sc": 0}, {"name": 905279830467581057, "sc": 0},
     {"name": 129057210578125985, "sc": 0}, {"name": 502801758921868921, "sc": 0}]

searchingId = 129057210578125985
a = True if list(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == searchingId, l)) else False
print(a)
```

Comment: Привет, нужна маленькая помощь. Как это можно вставить в мой код без ошибок? Просто немного туплю. Спасибо.

Comment: А, извини что потревожил. Исправил свой bad-code, удачи :)